# how does keepalived announce vip mac

Tags: keep-alive, arp

I have a cluster with server A(192.168.1.11) and B(192.168.1.12), both servers are configured to be "real server", let's say, listening on 80.

Both servers are also "virtual server", configured by keepalived, with IP 192.168.1.110

Things work find, floating VIP would redirect all 192.168.1.110:80 requests to A/B. I would omit the configuration details here.

Which I want to know is, how does keepalived announce VIP mac so the other machines on the same vxnet can update its arp table in time.

I've tried `tcpdump -i eth0 arp -qn` on A/B, but seems no any arp request sent during keepalived switching A/B' node status (from BACKUP to MASTER).

Comment: Do not grep when tcpdump arp request, seems not working in this case. i dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion:

Keepalived uses VRRP, and [VRRP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3768) states that when converting from BACKUP to MASTER, it would send a [gratuitous ARP request](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP) to broadcasting announce arp updates to neighborhoods.

> - If the Master_Down_Timer fires, then:
>
>   - Send an ADVERTISEMENT
>   - Broadcast a gratuitous ARP request containing the virtual
>     router MAC address for each IP address associated with the
>     virtual router
>   - Set the Adver_Timer to Advertisement_Interval
>   - Transition to the {Master} state
>
>   endif